# How to get Touchscreen to use Mouse Events instead of Touch Events in C# app

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, mouse

I have developed a C# app that overrides the PreviewMouseUp, PreviewMouseMove, and PreviewMouseDown events in some custom controls to allow scrolling a scroll viewer by clicking and dragging.  This custom code works great on non-touch screens when the mouse is used to drag and scroll, but when I use it on a real touch screen monitor it fails to work because the PreviewMouseUp does not get fired when the monitor is touched and dragged with a finger.

I want to be able to use my existing code with minimal changes.  This would allow me to use the mouse to click/drag while debugging on my laptop, and use the touch screen to touch/drag.

Is there anyway to configure a windows 7 computer to treat all touches (PreviewTouchUp, PreviewTouchDown, and PreviewTouchMove) as mouse events instead?

UPDATE:  I forgot to mention.  I thought that if the Touch events are not handled, than .NET automatically raises the Mouse events afterwards.  This does not appear to be happening even though none of the code I wrote handles the Touch Events currently.  Any ideas why this may be happening?

Thanks,
brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to use the same method for both, something like this:

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    OnPreviewTouchMouseUp(e);
}

protected override void OnPreviewTouchUp(TouchEventArgs e)
{
    OnPreviewTouchMouseUp(e);
}

private void OnPreviewTouchMouseUp(EventArgs e)
{

}
```

The only difference will be the way you get the coordinates of the mouse/touch:

For touch:

```
e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;
```

For mouse:

```
e.GetPosition(this);
```

Comment: This caused me duplicate behavior on touching. Because on Touch, both events executed: Touch and Mouse. Could you help me fix that?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf, use `e.handled = true`; in het `OnPreviewTouchUp` event handler.