# WPF with Mvvm Light handling mouse and touch

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, touch

Currently I have to develop a very simple WPF user control that allows the user to select several points on a canvas. The difficulty that I encounter, is that uses with a touch screen should be able to so by triggering a TouchDown event whereas users that don't have touch screen should use the mouse and thus trigger a MouseLeftButtonDown event. Is there a simple way to handle these two cases without duplicating code? Also, I need to use Mvvm Light, so code-behind solutions like [How to get Touchscreen to use Mouse Events instead of Touch Events in C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245551/how-to-get-touchscreen-to-use-mouse-events-instead-of-touch-events-in-c-sharp-ap) won't do the trick.

Comment: Just as a question: why are you using MVVM for a "very simple" WPF app?

Answer (score 2):

Your linked question provides an answer for you, whether you are using MVVM or not. Using MVVM does *not* mean that you cannot handle UI control events. It just means that you should write an `Attached Property` to handle them for you. So, your answer is yes, you can handle the two events together and in almost the same way as your linked page suggests.

Your only difference is that the handler must be attached to the events in an `Attached Property`. Rather than go over the whole story once again here, I'll just briefly explain the procedure and request that you view my answer from the [What's the best way to pass event to ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285577/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-event-to-viewmodel/21285863#21285863) question for a code example.

First [declare your `Attached Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#custom) with its getter and setter and ensure that it has a [`PropertyChangedCallback` handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attached. The `PropertyChangedCallback` handler is where you attach your single handler to the events (the code example just attaches a single event). This just means that it will only attach the handler to the events when your `Attached Property` is set. Finally, just add your single handler to handle the two events.