# How can I combine Touch and Mouse Event Handlers without producing duplicate behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I am working on a WPF application which is being used on a Touch Screen Tablet. I develop using VS2015 IDE and I use my Mouse to debug.

I must handle buttons' `down` and `up` events to execute certain tasks. I use `PreviewMouse` and `PreviewTouch` event handlers and I have a problem in every case I use:

- **Case 1:** Using `PreviewMouseDown`,`PreviewMouseUp`,`PreviewTouchDown` and `PreviewTouchUp`. For each button, I need to duplicate my code to include separate Touch and Mouse Event handlers *but* the exact same functionality. I do this for me to be able to use the Application (Mouse) and for the the user to use it (Touch). **Problem**: Touch Event Handlers executes Mouse Event Handlers; Causing the application to duplicate the behavior. Ex: A button that increments `x` by one, will increment by one if you "Click" it but increment by two if you "Touch" it.
- **Case 2:** Using `Click`, `PreviewMouseUp` and `PreviewTouchUp`. **Problem:** The `PreviewTouchUp` and `PreviewMouseUp` do not get called on *Mouse Click*.
- **Case 3:** Create a method for each button and call it from both Touch and Mouse events like [How to get Touchscreen to use Mouse Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245551/how-to-get-touchscreen-to-use-mouse-events-instead-of-touch-events-in-c-sharp-ap). **Problem:** Duplicate behavior (method gets called twice)
- **Case 4:** Remove all Touch events since `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp` are being executed on any Touch. The behavior works but I need to Touch certain positions on the button in order for it to execute. (Transparency? I must touch exactly one position - like a mouse?)
- **Case 5:** Using `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` instead of `Preview`. Didn't work on Touch at all, touching any position on the button.

I want something similar to this [Prevent a WPF application to interpret touch events as mouse events](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b05e550-19c0-46a2-b19c-40f40c8bf0ec/prevent-a-wpf-application-to-interpret-touch-events-as-mouse-events?forum=wpf) but only on the tablet. I still need to use my mouse in my environment. How can I fix that?

**Button sample XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="locationScrollUpButton" Margin="0,5,5,0" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" PreviewMouseUp="locationScrollUpButton_PreviewMouseUp" PreviewMouseDown="locationScrollUpButton_PreviewMouseDown" BorderThickness="0" PreviewTouchDown="locationScrollUpButton_PreviewTouchDown" PreviewTouchUp="locationScrollUpButton_PreviewTouchUp" >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="locationUpButtonText" Text="Up" FontSize="13" Margin="0,2,0,4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image x:Name="locationUpButtonImage" Source="/ProjectName;component/Resources/CaptureView/Location-Scroll-Up-White.png" Width="55" Height="60"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: try using this condition as a guard see if it works. `Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed`

Comment: @M.kaz I see ! I think I got what you mean. Xaml should look like this: `... PreviewMouseUp="Button_PreviewMouseUp" PreviewTouchUp="Button_PreviewMouseUp"...` but different events no? **Edit:** Use that condition where? (or what do you mean by guard)

Comment: dirty way.....using a debugger see which one get executed first. if touch event called first set a boolean value to `true`. for example `touch = true` then use a guard for next mouse event. `if(!touch) /* do things */  else touch = false;`. in this way you always suspend mouse events after touch events. if mouse events gets executed first use the same logic.

Comment: @M.Kaz I have an idea ! why not get rid of the whole Touch events? since Mouse's are being called on Touch right? But.. let's say the button should change a variable from `x` to `y` on click and back to `x` on release. The behavior doesn't happen on _every_ touch. it only happens almost 1/3 of the times. Do you have any idea why?? Is it like, the mouse event is looking for a single position but I am touching several positions with my finger, so it doesn't execute unless I touch exactly one position? or something like that?

Comment: @M.ka I can't use a debugger on the touch tablet for now or the soon future :(

Comment: can you show xaml part. not whole code but the part that you define events.

Comment: @M.Kaz I added it and also mentioned that I am using `PreviewMouse` events and not the normal ones.

Comment: @M I ended up with the dirty way :D See answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up doing it using a cool hack. Based on Ahmad's answer on this other question [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285335/why-my-mouse-event-handlers-are-not-working-when-i-have-touch-event-handlers) we know the fire order of the handlers:

On Touch Devices:

> TouchDown > PreviewMouseDown > TouchUp > PreviewMouseUp

On Non Touch:

> PreviewMouseDown > PreviewMouseUp

And based on @M.Kazem comments here. The fix now looks something like this:

```
private bool ButtonPreview = true;
private void Button_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    // task 1
    ButtonPreview = false;
}
private void Button_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    // task 2
    // ..
}
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ButtonXPreview)
    {
        // task 1
    }
    else
        ButtonXPreview = true;

}
private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (ButtonXPreview)
    {
        // task 2
    }
    else
        ButtonXPreview = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @AhmedKarim :)

Answer (score 10):

Check the StylusDevice property of the MouseEventArgs.  If it is null, then the mouse event is not a promoted touch event.  If it's not null, then the StylusDevice will be the touch device that initiated the touch that got promoted.

Comment: Nice sounds easy could you provide some code for future reference?

Comment: This answer is better then the accepted answer! `e.StylusDevice == null` -> **Mouse** | `e.StylusDevice != null` -> **Touch**